# Spatial correlogram - alternatives?

Tags: spatial

I am running a project looking at modelling future deforestation and natural regeneration in the Atlantic Forest, Brazil. The data set is very large.

I have run an incremental Spatial correlogram in Arcgis and the output was saying there were no peaks, I have read that in this case you have to justify your scale of analysis using some other criteria. I am stuck at to what this means.

I have tried running the collogram in r using the Spdep and ncf but both say that it can not be run due to memory storage.

Some info on data being used

1. I have produced a raster map with all deforestation points on it.
2. Converted this into a point map
3. Added coordinates to the points

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what the question is...

Comment: Hi Wyatt, Sorry for the poor presentation. I need to find a peak point in order to justify my scale of analysis. The problem is when I run the  incremental Spatial correlogram it gives me a graph with a z-score that just continues to rise with increasing distances; there is no peak. When I look at the help option on Arcgis it suggests that I should "justify your scale of analysis using some other criteria" and I completely out of ideas as to what this means? Ive tried running the correlogram in r and it runs out of memory. Thank you in advance for any ideas or suggestions.